# Intersection of two column spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let the matrices A and B be:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix} and \space
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

If $C(A)$ and $C(B)$ are the vector spaces generated by the columns of A and B, show that $C(A) \cap C(B)$ is a vector space and describe it.

I started to tackle this problem by transforming the two matrices in:

$$A' = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} and \space
B' = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

and so the base of the column spaces are:

$$Basis(A) = \{\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \}$$ and $$Basis(B) = \{\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \}$$

And so the intersection between the column spaces is:
$$C(A) \cap C(B) = Basis(A) = Basis(B)$$

Am I right? I'm not sure this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't make sense: You've reduced $A$ to $A'$ via *row reduction*, but this operation preserves the row space, not the column space. Indeed, we can see that the proposed $Basis(A)$ cannot span the column space of $A$, as the last entry of any element in the span of $Basis(A)$ is zero, but this is not even true of the first column of $A$.

One can modify your approach, though, by carrying out *column reduction* instead (equivalently, row-reducing $A^T$ and then taking the transpose). In this case, though, the matrices are simple enough that one can carry this out more or less by inspection. (In fact, $B$ itself is already column-reduced.)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. Drop another comment here if you have any more questions about carrying out the operation, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I did the row-reducing transformation in the transpose of A and found its basis. Then I compared it to the basis of B and found that the intersection of the column spaces is the column vector (1 1 1).

Comment: Great, that's what I get (and what it looks SiongthyeGoh got in their answer, too).

Answer (score 1):

A basis of $A$ is $\left\{\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{array} \right] ,\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1\\ 1\end{array} \right]\right\}$.

Given a vector, a quick way to know that it is in the column space of $A$ is to check that the second and third component are equal.

A basis of $B$ is $\left\{\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{array} \right] ,\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\\ 0\end{array} \right]\right\}$.

Given a vector, a quick way to know that it is in the column space of $A$ is to check that the first and second component are equal.

What about $C(A) \cap C(B)$?

It is the space where there all the components are equal.

$$C(A) \cap C(B)=span((1,1,1)^T)$$

Comment: thanks! that was very helpful

Comment: for me, the basis of B is {(1 1 0) and (0 0 1)} not {(1 1 1) and (1 1 0)}. Could you explain how you got there?

Comment: Hi, your basis is correct as well. basis is not unique. (1,1,1)=(1,1,0)+(0,0,1), we are in the same space.